# How to make explicit the arguments returned by pipe | to use them in subsequent command

Tags: linux, bash

I have a directory tree looking like this:

```
dir1
  |---dir2-1
  |---dir2-2
  |---dir2-3
  |--- ...
```

I simply want to create a new directory say `dir3-1` under each of the current leaves `dir2-X`, resulting in:

```
dir1
  |---dir2-1
        |---dir3-1
  |---dir2-2
        |---dir3-1
  |---dir2-3
        |---dir3-1
  |--- ...
```

Can I do that with pipe `|` ? I naively tried to make explicit the arguments returned by the pipe by using `$1` to subsequently use them with `mkdir` but it doesn't seem to be the right syntax.

The spirit of what I want to do is: `find . -name dir2-* | xargs -n1 mkdir $1/dir3-1`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A pipe doesn't pass any parameters; it takes the stdout from the first command and connects it to the stdin of the second command.

With `xargs`, you can specify a replacement field by using the `-I` option (see [KamilCuk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63138742/4518341)), but it's easier to use `find -exec`, which uses `{}` as the replacement field. Something like this:

```
find . -name 'dir2-*' -exec mkdir {}/dir3-1 \;
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure, why not:

```
find ./dir1 -maxdepth 2 -type d -name 'dir2-*' | xargs -d '\n' -I {} mkdir {}/dir3-1
```